# How to run vuejs-templates/webpack on live server instead of localhost

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-router

I have created my vue js project with vuejs-templates/webpack. Here is link whi i have use: [Webpack link](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

Now i want to run same thing on live server. I know i can use `npm run build` and generated code from `dist` directly work from server.

But i want to use my production code on live server.

For that i have installed Node js, Vue CLI and vuejs-templates/webpack on my UBUNTU server.

Also i changed `HOST` and `PORT` inside `config/index.js`

But when i use `npm run dev` it successfully compiled and give me proper location of running. But when i hit enter on that location in browser, it just goes time out and nothing to display.

If anyone know solution than please help.

Comment: maybe firewall problem or you might be still listening on localhost in which case you wont be able to access it from outside that server machine.

Comment: @MatJ i have changed Host and Port. Does i need to change anything else?

Comment: Can you access it from inside the server?

Comment: @MatJ. Thanks. It was firewall issue. now resolved it.